# PHP - Path to the Windows Downloads folder?

Tags: php, environment-variables

In PHP, I need to retrieve the path to the *Downloads* folder on Windows.

I'm currently using a static path, but I'd like to make the username dynamic:

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\ravi.kumar\Downloads';
```

I need the username of the system where the downloads folder exists.
Any code query which can give either the Windows username or the *Downloads* folder path would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works for me:**

```
$dir = getenv('HOMEDRIVE').getenv('HOMEPATH').'\Downloads';
```

You can check the other available variables here:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3234-environment-variables-windows-10-a.html

I hope this helps!